# How can I limit a string when parsing XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, character, limit, feed

I am writing a custom landing page in PHP parsing an XML product feed.  The product descriptions are very long, as it goes into technical information and specifications, so need to be condensed to read the first 200 characters. hopefully with a read more link once 200 characters has been reached.

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');

foreach ($xml->item as $item) { ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="lhs">
    <h3><a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>"><?php echo $item->brand.' '.$item->title ?></a></h3>
    <p class="pri">&pound;<?php echo $item->price ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $item->description; ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="rhs">
        <img src="<?php echo $item->image_link ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title ?>" height="150" />
        </div>
        </div>  

<?php
}
?>
```

Please could anyone advise what else I need to add? I can follow basic patterns in PHP, I just need some guidance.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the $short_description line.
Edited with some basic js example of "Show more"

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('feed.xml');

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    $short_description = substr($item->description, 0, 200);
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="lhs">
        <h3><a href="<?php echo $item->link ?>"><?php echo $item->brand . ' ' . $item->title ?></a></h3>
        <p class="pri">&pound;<?php echo $item->price ?></p>
        <p id="shown"><?php echo $short_description; ?>... <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('shown').style.display = 'none'; this.style.display = 'none'; return false;">Show more</a></p>
        <p id="hidden"><?php echo $item->description; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="rhs">
        <img src="<?php echo $item->image_link ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title ?>" height="150" />
        </div>
    </div>  

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Rikudou.  I didn't opt to use the JavaScript but it works great.

On another note, how could I limit how many results are displayed, eg 10?  Or do I need to start another thread for that?

Comment: Probably it would be better to start a new thread, but simple solution would be to add $i = 0; before the foreach. Before the very end of foreach loop add $i++; and then put somewhere inside the loop this condition: if($i === 10) { break; }